Using Toad for Oracle the data grid icon are is about 200 pixels high. Any ideas how to adjust th
Toad for Oracle version Toad for Oracle Xpert (64-bit) 17.0.341.1977
Any idea what causes the data grid icon area to be 200 pixels high. This wastes a lot of screen space.
There don't appear to be any settings when right click or in the view options.

